# Angular Element Height is 0 without setTimeout

Tags: angular

I have a custom directive and has below code to set height if the element contains some class.

```js
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains('myclass')) {
      const content = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.child');
      console.log(content.scrollHeight);
    }
  }
```

Above method will return 0, but if I use `setTimeout()` it will return the element height value correctly

```js
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains('myclass')) {
      const content = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.child');
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(content.scrollHeight);
      }, 100);
    }
  }
```

This seems like a hack and I'm not sure what is the correct way to retrieve element height after the content has been rendered. Some suggest to use `ngAfterViewChecked` life cycle but the result is still the same, 0.

The HTML

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="accordion-wrapper is-open"
       accordion>
    <div class="accordion-header">
      <div>Title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the template to see what is inside the child and where it came from

Comment: Updated. Basically I'm trying to open accordion content if is-open class is added to the element.